# How to build a very close shaving shaver?

Tags: shaving

Summary: *There’s a great fashion in many countries about wearing a dotted style of beard (sorry I can’t really translate this, but this is the level below stubble). I don't want this.*

When you use classic razors you get a beardless style, which is now completely old fashioned except in some asian factories where peoples are fired if they have a black dot on their face in the morning *(in my own country the right to have beard in factories date from a massive strike in 1905)*.
So the industry, *(Wilkinson and others)* stop to produce shavers that produce that style of shaving.

This went so far that it’s no longer possible for people, in my country, to shave their heads to get shining skin style. *(you even see a dotless area on people choosing that style because of hair loss)*. I never saw a shaved head without dots.  Even in our army this is the case.

I tried various models and kind of blades, starting when I was 16 which is not so long ago, but I’m still unsatisfied with the length of my beard. I've even tried blades that were not build for shaving purposes. I certainly won’t go to methods used by women *(things like hair removal, even if I want their result)*.

This is not about the method for shaving *(I know this implies daily shaving)*. For common examples, I really find current beards of George cloney or Daniel Craig too long for me.

**Since there’s no place to buy them**, how to build my own shaver from scratch that would be able to achieve a beardless style? That is a razor which would be able to cut so short that it won’t leave black dots on my face.

Comment: Wait -- are you looking for short stubble?  Have you see the Miami Device?

Comment: I doubt its a "fashion" it's just the quality of present razors isn't the same as old school straight razors. Besides, hair grows daily.

Comment: Could you simplify and make your post not so extremely chatty?  It makes your question unclear. Do you ask for how to get the best clean shave? Or do you ask for how to get an even but very short length of shave?

Comment: I would not shave with anything I made myself, personally. :( I am curious however what you are exactly asking for. Could you post a picture with the length you want? Are you saying you don't want a clean shave(no hair at all), but you also don't want a shave that leaves stubble(like with a beard trimmer)? Something in between?

Comment: @JGTaylor : For my parents, having a clean beard means having pile of equals length *(doing this require shaving)*. I know about the *“you want the same skin as a girl on your face”* remark *(though in the meantime wearing a long beard is definitely linked to pro terrorism persons)*. I hate being fashioned and wearing a 5 o clock pm beard is definitely the norm.

Comment: @JustDoIt : Despite safety razors exist for centuries here, a few barber shops still exists in the country. **However, I fear to spent 1 hour in public and disturbing everyone by insisting for shorter whereas this is no longer possible.**

Answer (score 3):

I've edited your post quite a bit as it was very chatty, and confusing. Hopefully I've maintained your original meaning, even though it doesn't really make sense.

The fashion hasn't in most places I've heard about gone to such a step that razors aren't able to give you a clean shave. This sounds like more of a problem with your shaving technique, than a problem with the razor.

So possibly the following will help you, where I use a standard razor and does the following when I shave my self:

- Wash/rinse your face with warm water, and apply shaving foam/gel
- Starting on one cheek, I shave going downwards allowing the razor to glide along my skin
- After completing the cheek, and under my chin on that side, I shave the opposite way (against the hair), to get an even closer shave
- Repeat for other side/cheek, first going downwars, and then upwards against the hairs
- Finish off with shaving above and under mouth, and the final portion under the chin
- At very end, rinse off any excess shaving foam/gel, and apply after shave if you like that

Comment: `The fashion hasn't in most places I've heard about gone to such a step that razors aren't able to give you a clean shave.`For the peoples who shave their hair *(not me)*, you can really see the difference between those who have all their hairs and those who suffer from hair loss.

Comment: @user2284570, There will be a difference between those who have lost all hair growth, and those shaving. But I'll doubt you see much hair/beard stubs on people shaving regularly (and often), before on a very close inspection. So still I believe that the OP has mainly an issue with how to shave, rather than needing a different razor.

Comment: Yeah, you need to be at least 4 meter to notice it. But it’s not linked with regularly shaving, it’s simply the fashion. I found that [example advert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vDSgzOlb-eo) which is broadcasted in 1080p on our country tv channels. However the quality of the official youtube video *(320p)*  isn’t enough to show that the hairs aren’t cut so short.

Comment: @user2284570, Are you talking about shaving your head, or shaving your beard?  It seems like we're cross communicating.

Comment: Shaving beard of course. But taking hair shaving as an example is better since *(unlike beard)* the shining skin style is *(usually)* the thing you want to achieve *(I don’t want hair shaving of course)*. And this share the phenomenon that the razor required to cut so short no longer exist *(for both hair and beard)* here.

Answer (score 1):

The best shaves I've ever had were from an old-fashioned "cut-throat" straight razor.  I could get a shave that would leave my cheeks and chin positively shiny for many hours, and wouldn't show actual stubble for two days (this was in my late 20s).

In conjunction with the traditional razor, I used a hot water soak to soften my whiskers, hot soap from a mug applied with a shaving brush, and an after shave astringent that tightened the skin pores -- this last may be a bad idea, depending how curly your beard is.

Shaving with a straight razor requires practice and patience, and a good deal of care to begin with, but the results are unequalled by any other method.

Comment: `The best shaves I've ever had were from an old-fashioned "cut-throat" straight razor`. I totally agree, the problem is they no longer cut so short. Does the`shave astringent`help at erasing the black dot effect ?

Comment: In my experience, getting rid of "black dots" revolves around cutting the whisker below the skin surface.  And I'd confidently state that a straight razor will cut just as closely in 2015 as it did in 1990, when I used one regularly.  Not very good for shaving your head, though, if that's what you're after.

Comment: I cited Hair Shaving as an example of the situation. I used to think “*I hate being fashioned, I’d rather not shave myself at all if it’s for steal having beard*”. But with recent events this starts to get a stronger connotation *(I don’t believe in Allah)*.

Comment: `In my experience, getting rid of "black dots" revolves around cutting the pile below the skin surface`Yes I know it, but I never figured how to achieve this.

Comment: Try this link for how to get that kind of shave.  https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=shave%20with%20a%20straight%20razor

Comment: Mmmmh, I don’t see differences from the ways I tried.

Comment: It's possible that if your beard is very dark, or your skin fairly pale or transparent, that there'll be no way to make the hairs beneath the skin surface invisible.  If that's the case, you may need to investigate waxing,  select a beard style that won't get you mistaken for a radical, or consider laser hair eradication or electrolysis (both mostly permanent, that is, the hair mostly doesn't grow back).

Comment: Yes, I’m white with dark hairs.`consider laser hair eradication or electrolysis (both mostly permanent, that is, the hair mostly doesn't grow back).` but sounds like hair removing for womens.

Comment: Those methods are more commonly used by women, but work equally well for any hair -- body, face, or head -- for either sex.  Waxing is also commonly used by women, but is also equally effective for men, and not permanent.  Epilation (a machine that pulls the hairs individually) is in the same class as waxing, but less difficult to do yourself.

Comment: I’ll get the same jokes if I use that.